# Ordering rows to distribute common records evenly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following data:

```
+----+-------+---------+
| id | name  | country |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 | alice | usa     |
|  2 | bob   | usa     |
|  3 | chad  | russia  |
|  4 | derek | china   |
|  5 | ethan | usa     |
+----+-------+---------+
```

Is there any way in sql to reorder my table [besides ORDER BY RAND()] which would allow me to display records in such a way that each consecutive row shows a unique country. i.e. if the previous row also  has the country 'usa', show a record with a different country for as long as possible.

In the above case, one of the possible outputs could be:

```
+----+-------+---------+
| id | name  | country |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 | alice | usa     |
|  3 | chad  | russia  |
|  2 | bob   | usa     |
|  4 | derek | China   |
|  5 | ethan | usa     |
+----+-------+---------+
```

I'm basically trying to distribute the rows so they appear more spread-out in cases where the majority of the records have a common dominating value.

Comment: This is not possible.  If you had one more row with `'usa'` then no such ordering would exist.

Comment: Hence the 'for as long as possible'. If not, it could display the remaining 'usa' rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little contrived, perhaps...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
,country VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'alice','usa'),
(2,'bob','usa'),
(3,'chad','russia'),
(4,'derek','china'),
(5,'ethan','usa'),
(6,'fred','usa');

SELECT id,name,country FROM (SELECT *, @i:=@i+1 i FROM my_table,(SELECT @i:=0) vars ORDER BY country = 'usa') a ORDER BY MOD(i,4), id;
+----+-------+---------+
| id | name  | country |
+----+-------+---------+
|  2 | bob   | usa     |
|  3 | chad  | russia  |
|  5 | ethan | usa     |
|  4 | derek | china   |
|  6 | fred  | usa     |
|  1 | alice | usa     |
+----+-------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Reviewing comments, it seems that what you're really looking for is something like this...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.country = x.country 
   AND y.id <= x.id 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id 
 ORDER 
    BY COUNT(*), country;
+----+-------+---------+
| id | name  | country |
+----+-------+---------+
|  4 | derek | china   |
|  3 | chad  | russia  |
|  1 | alice | usa     |
|  2 | bob   | usa     |
|  5 | ethan | usa     |
|  6 | fred  | usa     |
+----+-------+---------+
```

Comment: This helps but the catch is at no point will I know that the table is densely populated with 'usa' only since the data changes everyday. I'm basically looking for a solution that can ensure that the value of the previous record is different from the current record for as long as possible

Comment: @JKerr That's an easier requirement, but that's not what you asked for. 'USA','Russia','China','USA','USA' (or 'Russia','China','USA','USA','USA') is a simpler requirement than 'USA','Russia','USA','China','USA'

Comment: Thank you! Your revised answer solves my issue. But it'll be really interesting to see a solution for the 'USA','Russia','USA','China','USA' scenario too

Comment: @JKerr Unfortunately, that one's above my pay grade.